Trace operation as contraction - how can we contract only contravariant indices?
Sorry if this question is too pedantic, but I come from a mathematical background and want to get the details in my thesis correct.
The example for tensors and contraction I so often read online (especially in the context of tensors for computer science), is that a matrix $M \epsilon \mathbb{R}^2$ corresponds to a (2,0) tensor $M_{i,j}$, and taking its trace is nothing other than contracting the two indices: $tr(M) = M_{k,k}$.
Here's my question: The more rigorous definition for contraction only allows for contraction along corresponding contra- and covariant indices, meaning I could only take the trace of a (1,1)-tensor. However, matrices are usually defined as (2,0)-tensors, so how could the trace operation possibly correspond to contraction? Am I mistaken, that one can only contract contra- and covariant indices?

Matrices are not defined as $(2,0)$-tensors. They are defined as $(1,1)$-tensors; a linear map $V \to V$ is the same thing as a map $\mathbb R \to V\otimes V^*$ which is the same thing as $V\otimes V^*$.
To contract two indices of the same type you need an isomorphism $V\cong V^*$, which is the same thing as a non-degenerate bilinear form $V\times V \to \mathbb R$.
When you "contract" two indices of the same variance, or write matrices as $(2,0)$- or $(0,2)$-tensors, you are implicitly using the standard inner product on $\mathbb R$.

What does $\mathbb R \to V\otimes V^$ mean? I thought that given a bilinear form $B: V \times V^ \to \mathbb R$ we can construct a linear map $f:V \to V$ using $f(v)(\underline u)=B(v,\underline u)$ ($\underline u$ is a covector). The vector space of bilinear maps like $B$ can be thought of as the dual of $V^* \otimes V$ but I cannot connect it to $\mathbb R \to V\otimes V^*$.

@TedBlack You can move a vector space factor from one side of $\to$ to the other by going to the dual. The space of $(p,q)$-tensors ($p$ contravariant indices and $q$ covariant) is equivalently the space of multilinear maps $(V^)^p\times V^q\to\mathbb R$ or just the space $V^{\otimes p}\otimes(V^)^{\otimes q}.$ The first definition makes $(1,0)$-tensors elements of $V^{**},$ when just $V$ would do. The two definitions are connected by double-dualization. In the $(1,1)$ case, the canonical isomorphism $V\otimes V^*\to\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$ is $(u\otimes v)(w)=v(w)u,$ extended by linearity.

OK so in theory $V \to \mathbb R$ is the same as $\mathbb R \to V^*$?

@TedBlack A linear function $f : \mathbb R \to W$ for any vector space $W$ is entirely determined by $f(1)$: $$f(\alpha) = \alpha f(1).$$ These linear transformations form a vector space $$Hom(\mathbb R,W):={f:\mathbb R\to W;|;f\text{ is linear}}$$ and we easily have a natural isomorphism $Hom(\mathbb R,W)\cong W$. By definition $V^* = Hom(V,\mathbb R)$, so $$Hom(V,\mathbb R)=V^\cong Hom(\mathbb R,V^).$$

Thanks @NicholasTodoroff this is another example that good mathematics has a sense of humour.

Simple answer to the question: you can't contract on indices of the same type, so some assumption or adjustment must be made. Usually this adjustment deals with the metric, which acts as a way of raising and lowering indices.
If $M$ is a tensor of type $(2,0)$, then you cannot perform contraction. This is because $M$ takes two arguments, both of which are covectors, and there is no way to associate two convectors to a scalar in a meaningful way without introducing another operation to sum them against. In order to perform contraction, $M$ must be a tensor of type $(1,1)$, which is not the case.
There is a "trick" we perform when we are given a metric $g$. Since $g$ is sort of the magic tensor that measures distance and is assumed to be given to us, we can lower and index of $M$ through the sum
$$
\bar{M}^\mu_\nu=g_{\mu\gamma}M^{\mu\gamma}
$$
This new tensor $\bar{M}$ is of type $(1,1)$, and so we can perform contraction. Now when we contract, we get a scalar $\alpha$
$$
\alpha=g_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu}
$$
which is the trace of $\bar{M}$.
The long story short here is that without a metric (or some other notion of a symmetric non-degenerate tensor $g$) there is no reasonable way to define contraction of tensors of the same type of index. Regarding tensors in computer science, I am not sure how a basis is taken into considering or what metric is used, and so it's hard to say given your use case.

Thank you! Would it be correct to think of metrics as a generalization of base change matrices in linear algebra? Or even simpler, an extension of "Column swaps"?

Not quite. A metric in this case is basically a generalization of an inner product. Starting in one basis, define an inner product between vectors, and name the resulting matrix that you get from that definition $g$. Then let that matrix $g_{\mu\nu}$ be the components of some tensor of type $(0,2)$, and so it transforms with the change of basis.

Matrices are not tensors at all, although they can be used to represent certain tensors. When this is being done, each one of the two indexing directions (row and column indices) in the matrix can be called either covariant or contravariant, depending on the type of tensor being represented. One can compute the trace of any square matrix, but whether the result says anything meaningful about the tensor that it represents, namely something that does not depend on the basis used when representing the tensor, depends on the situation: it is the case only if both directions have opposite variance.
To be clear, a matrix is just (essentially) a rectangular array of numbers, and one can do with a matrix $M$ it whatever can be defined for this array. Supposing for concreteness that $M$ has dimension $(9,9)$, one could for sure define its trace, but also its determinant, or the product of its four corner entries, or test whether it describes a valid Sudoku grid, or whatever. This to dispel most "one cannot define" claims for such concrete values; one is free to do a lot of things, although they are not always very useful in a given situation.
Tensors are certain types of values related to a vector space$~V$; examples are its vectors, linear forms on $V$, linear self-maps (endomorphisms) $V\to{V}$, bilinear forms on $V$, elements of the tensor product space $V\otimes{V}$, and so on. Unless $V$ is some very particular kind of vector space, there is usually no direct way to describe these values with things like matrices that are made up of numbers only; such a description would require an ordered basis of $V$ to be chosen first. Once this is done, each kind of tensor has (by a chosen convention) its own encoding scheme; the most basic kind is vectors of $V$, which can be represented by the coefficients of the unique linear combination of the basis vectors equal to it, conventionally written in order in a column (assuming finite dimension here). Several different kinds of tensor can all be represented by matrices: in the above list the endomorphisms of$~V$, the bilinear forms, and the elements of $V\otimes{V}$; in each case the conventional encoding fixes a way (different for each kind) in which matrices represent these tensors.
Now it is important to realise the way in which the encoding depends on the chosen basis. With few exceptions, the value encoding a fixed tensor will vary with the basis. The dependence can be described by formulas for the change of basis, in terms of the change of basis matrix that describes the relation between the two bases involved in the change. Encoding schemes for different types of tensors have different change of basis formulas, and it turns out that there is a way to describe those formulas uniformly after classifying each of the indexing directions in the encoding scheme as covariant or contravariant. Apparently the nomenclature is such that in the encoding scheme for ordinary vectors, the unique indexing direction is contravariant (this contrarian choice is related to what was chosen to be the change of basis matrix; the change to vector coordinates is that of multiplying by the inverse of the change of basis matrix).
Contraction operations are operations that transform the numeric objects that can be used to represent tensors (such as square matrices) into smaller such objects; the basic example is taking the trace of a matrix (giving a simple number, without any indexing left). It turns out that under a given encoding, the resulting value sometimes still transforms by a change of basis formula, so that the result can be interpreted as representing (on the same basis) a lower rank tensor meaningfully related to the original tensor. This happens for a single contraction precisely if one has contracted according to one covariant and one contravariant direction (and the contracted value transforms according to variance of the remaining, non-contracted, directions).
Now to cut to the chase (this is getting too long): of the three types of tensors that can be represented by square matrices, the bilinear forms have both indexing directions covariant, the endomorphisms have one (horizontal) indexing direction covariant and the other (vertical) direction contravariant, and for vectors in $V\otimes{V}$ both directions are contravariant. The above than means that taking the trace of a matrix only gives a value that "transforms properly" if that matrix was used to encode an endomorphism (a rank 0 tensor is just a number, its "encoding" by a number is independent of any basis, so "transforms properly" here means that it is invariant). Indeed, the trace of a matrix of an endomorphism does not depend on the basis used, but when a matrix is used to represent a bilinear form or an element of $V\otimes{V}$, the trace varies with the basis used and does not say anything meaningful about the tensor encoded by the matrix.

Your understanding is correct, in general we can only contract contravariant indices with covariant ones, and the trace is only defined for $(1,1)$-tensors.
However, there are many contexts in which one has additional structure, such as a nondegenerate bilinear form (usually symmetric or symplectic) or a distinguished basis. In these contexts indices can be raised and lowered, and it is often convenient to define trace for $(2,0)$- or $(0,2)$-tensors using the lowering/raising operator implicitly. The trace defined like this is invariant under linear maps which preserve the additional structure (usually orthogonal/symplectic/monomial group).
In the context of tensors for computation, one always has the basis in which the computation is performed, and while in the analysis of the problem it is useful to distinguish covariant and contravariant indices, by the time we have the computation, covariant and contravariant indices are the same and tensors at this point are just multi-way arrays in the fixed basis. This has an effect that tutorials focused on computational side usually do not bother with covariant/contravariant indices  (unfortunate, in my opinion, as it is often important to the understanding of why the computation is done).
